# differentiating an expression that holds true for discrete values of x

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let's say I have an expression of the form :

```
a + b + c  = d
```

where `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are all differentiable functions of `x`, and the expression holds true only when `x` is a whole number. `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` have the same domain

I am trying to figure out if I can use the sum rule of differentiation to differentiate both sides of the expression to get :

```
a' + b' + c' = d'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most certainly you cannot. For example, take

$$a(x)=0, b(x)=0, c(x)=\sin(\pi x), d(x)=-\sin(\pi x)$$

Then, for integer values of $x$, you have $$a(x)+b(x)+c(x)=0+0+0=0=d(x)$$

however the same is not true for the derivatives, since

$$c'(x)=\pi\cos(\pi x), d'(x)=-\pi\cos(\pi x)$$

which, for integer values of $x$, is equao to
$$c'(x)=\pi\cdot (-1)^x, d'(x)=\pi\cdot (-1)^{x+1} = -c'(x)$$

---

In general, your idea fails becaues you want to obtain information about $f'(x)$ while only having information about $f$ on a discrete set. The value of $f'(x)$ is dependent **only** on the values of $f$ **near** $x$, but for values near $x$, you have no other information about $f$ other than what $f(x)$ is.

Consider the following:

If you give me any value $\epsilon >0$, any collection of "edge" values $y_0, y_0', y_1, y_1'$, any pair of values $y, y'$ and any $x_0$, it is possible to construct a function with the following properties:

- $f(x_0-\epsilon) = y_0, f(x_0+\epsilon)=y_1$
- $f'(x_0-\epsilon)=y_0', f'(x_0+\epsilon)=y_1'$
- $f(x_0)=y_0$
- $f'(x_0)=y'_0$

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Any ideas on why the sum rule does not work? I cannot figure out the principle I'm violating in applying the sum rule here.

Comment: @WitchKingofAngmar I just added another paragraph to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Forget the equation with a sum $a+b+c=d$, which is irrelevant, and focus on $f=0$ where $f:=a+b+c-d$. (The sum rule plays no role in your question and is not broken.)

Your question is in fact "if $f$ cancels at every integer, does $f'$ also cancel ?"

No. Take $\sin(\pi x)$.

Comment: Makes sense. Can I then assume that the sum rule would fail for every expression which is true only for discrete values of `x`?

Comment: @WitchKingofAngmar: er no. The sum rule DOES NOT FAIL. You did not understand my answer.